# R to Python conversion: Gamma regression with offset, case weights and interaction of categorical variables

Tags: python, r, sas, statsmodels, glm

I feel little bit of pain converting more complex GLM models from R to python. I appreciate any help that will lead to getting fundamentally similar results in both languages. I have prepared (with ChatGPT help) a reproduceable example.

To my surprise python `statsmodels` package seems to handle interactions differently than R does (see the outputs below). I am basically one step from hardcoding the model matrix creation so that it contains same features as in R. But I do not want to give up too soon, as I still believe that there must be simpler approach to get (almost) the same results in python as in R.

## R

### Code

```
# Create sample dataset with 3 variables, offset and case weights
dt <- data.frame(target = c(1.5, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 3.0, 4.5, 5.5, 4.0, 3.5, 2.5, 3.0, 2.0, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 3.0), 
                 var1 = factor(c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D", "D", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D", "D", "A", "A", "B", "B")),
                 var2 = factor(c("X", "Y", "X", "Y", "X", "Y", "X", "Y", "X", "Y", "X", "Y", "X", "Y", "X", "Y", "X", "Y", "X", "Y")),
                 var3 = factor(c("M", "N", "N", "M", "N", "M", "M", "N", "N", "M", "M", "N", "M", "N", "N", "M", "M", "N", "N", "M")),
                 offset = c(1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2),
                 case_weights = c(1, 1.5, 2, 1.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 1.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 1.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 1.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 1.5))

# Fit the glm model with the dataset, with offset, case weights and interaction of categorical variables
fit <- glm(formula = as.formula("target ~ var1 + var2:var3"),
           offset = offset,
           weights = case_weights,
           family = Gamma(link="log"),
           data = dt)
summary(fit)
```

### Output

```
Call:
glm(formula = as.formula("target ~ var1 + var2:var3"), family = Gamma(link = "log"), 
    data = dt, weights = case_weights, offset = offset)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.0494  -0.5148  -0.1940   0.4460   1.1210  

Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept) -0.30812    0.34302  -0.898   0.3854  
var1B       -0.87547    0.38038  -2.302   0.0385 *
var1C       -0.12718    0.44326  -0.287   0.7787  
var1D       -1.18807    0.40693  -2.920   0.0119 *
var2X:var3M -0.04003    0.40421  -0.099   0.9226  
var2Y:var3M  0.13896    0.40131   0.346   0.7347  
var2X:var3N -0.13315    0.40397  -0.330   0.7470  
var2Y:var3N       NA         NA      NA       NA  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for Gamma family taken to be 0.5822375)

    Null deviance: 13.6545  on 19  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:  6.8235  on 13  degrees of freedom
AIC: 125.64

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 14
```

## Python

### Code

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

# Create sample dataset with 3 variables, offset and case weights
dt = pd.DataFrame({'target': [1.5, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 3.0, 4.5, 5.5, 4.0, 3.5, 2.5, 3.0, 2.0, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 3.0],
                   'var1': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B'],
                   'var2': ['X', 'Y', 'X', 'Y', 'X', 'Y', 'X', 'Y', 'X', 'Y', 'X', 'Y', 'X', 'Y', 'X', 'Y', 'X', 'Y', 'X', 'Y'],
                   'var3': ['M', 'N', 'N', 'M', 'N', 'M', 'M', 'N', 'N', 'M', 'M', 'N', 'M', 'N', 'N', 'M', 'M', 'N', 'N', 'M'],
                   'offset': [1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2],
                   'case_weights': [1, 1.5, 2, 1.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 1.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 1.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 1.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 1.5]})

# Fit the glm model with the dataset, with offset, case weights and interaction of categorical variables
fit = smf.glm(formula='target ~ var1 + var2:var3', 
              offset=dt['offset'], 
              data=dt, 
              family=sm.families.Gamma(link=sm.families.links.log()),
              freq_weights=dt['case_weights']).fit()
print(fit.summary())
```

### Output

```
                 Generalized Linear Model Regression Results
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                 target   No. Observations:                   20
Model:                            GLM   Df Residuals:                       23
Model Family:                   Gamma   Df Model:                            6
Link Function:                    log   Scale:                         0.32910
Method:                          IRLS   Log-Likelihood:                -55.981
Date:                Thu, 20 Apr 2023   Deviance:                       6.8235
Time:                        15:48:56   Pearson chi2:                     7.57
No. Iterations:                    36   Pseudo R-squ. (CS):             0.6458
Covariance Type:            nonrobust
=====================================================================================
                        coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Intercept            -0.3482      0.281     -1.240      0.215      -0.899       0.202
var1[T.B]            -0.8754      0.286     -3.061      0.002      -1.436      -0.315
var1[T.C]            -0.1272      0.333     -0.382      0.703      -0.780       0.526
var1[T.D]            -1.1880      0.306     -3.883      0.000      -1.788      -0.588
var3[T.N]            -0.0931      0.302     -0.309      0.758      -0.684       0.498
var2[T.Y]:var3[M]     0.1790      0.304      0.589      0.556      -0.416       0.774
var2[T.Y]:var3[N]     0.1332      0.304      0.439      0.661      -0.462       0.728
=====================================================================================
```

## EDIT I.

I am adding SAS code to reproduce R results.

## SAS

### Code

```
/* Create sample dataset with 3 variables, offset and case weights */
data dt;
input target var1 $ var2 $ var3 $ offset case_weights;
datalines;
1.5 A X M 1 1
2.0 A Y N 2 1.5
3.0 B X N 3 2
4.0 B Y M 2 1.5
2.5 C X N 1 1
3.5 C Y M 2 1.5
4.5 D X M 3 2
3.0 D Y N 2 1.5
4.5 A X N 1 1
5.5 A Y M 2 1.5
4.0 B X M 3 2
3.5 B Y N 2 1.5
2.5 C X M 1 1
3.0 C Y N 2 1.5
2.0 D X N 3 2
1.5 D Y M 2 1.5
2.5 A X M 1 1
3.5 A Y N 2 1.5
4.5 B X N 3 2
3.0 B Y M 2 1.5
;
run;

/* Fit the glm model with the dataset, with offset, case weights and interaction of categorical variables */
proc genmod data=dt;
class var1(REF="A") var2 var3;
model target = var1 var2*var3 / dist=gamma link=log offset=offset;
weight case_weights;
run;

/* Fit the glm model with the dataset, with offset, case weights and interaction of categorical variables */
proc hpgenselect data=dt;
class var1(REF="A") var2 var3 /param=GLM;
model target = var1 var2*var3 / Distribution=Gamma offset=offset link=log;
selection method=NONE details=all;
run;
```

### Output

Output differs a bit for `genmod` and `hpgenselect` methods, but that's fine, I know that I cannot expect exact numbers.

I will highly appreciate a python solution which will reproduce the R (and SAS) results. Thanks for the effort!

Comment: I don't know about the formula. However, scale also differs. R does not treat weights as case weights, residual degrees of freedom in R is based on number of rows not on sum(case_weights). df_resid in statsmodels uses sum(freq_weights).

Comment: Thanks for the insight! Models without interactions (keeping case weights & offset) provide the same results in python and R, however. So the difference seems to be in interactions handling. Also SAS and R results are compatible, I will update the post.